# Replace URL occurrence in string using PHP

Tags: php, replace

I want to replace the url in the following text with [FILENAME], where FILENAME is the name of the file.

```
check out this car http://somesite/ford.png
```

This will then appear like:

```
check out this car [ford]
```

This is my code so far:

```
$text = $_POST['text']; //get submitted post
$link = strstr($text, 'http://'); //look for an http
$filename = pathinfo ($link, PATHINFO_FILENAME); //get filename from $link
$result = str_replace($text,$link,"[".$filename."]"); // search on $text, find $link, replace it with $filename

echo $result;
```

At the moment, I am only getting back `[ford]`, where is all the other text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using `str_replace`

You have your parameters in the wrong order, you need to change them like so:

```
$result = str_replace($link,"[".$filename."]",$text);
```

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for documentation.

### Alternative (Regular Expression)

You could use a regular expression. This method is marginly slower, but it will use less code:

```
$result = preg_replace('/http(s?):\/\/[a-z]\/(.+)\.png/i', '[$1]', $text);
```

You can then alter your regular expression further by allowing other kinds of images like so:

```
$result = preg_replace('/http(s?):\/\/[a-z]\/(.+)\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)/i', '[$1]', $text);
```

### To Conclude

You can use either of the above methods, but in my opinion I would use the first. Regular Expressions can be brilliant, but they can also be unreliable if you define them incorrectly, or forget about a potential factor in the pattern.

Comment: hi thanks for giving a better alternative. out of curiosity how do you k now that `preg_replace` is slower than `str_replace`?

Comment: @user1933824 Regular expressions generally use more CPU as they take more processing. I would stick with your method personally as it is more reliable. The above regular expression would have to be altered if you wanted to match a domain such as `http://example.net/ford.png`. And that is where regular expressions can be unreliable because you need to account for all formats of domains.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = preg_replace ('/http:\/\/somesite\/(.+)\.png/', '[$1]', $text);
```

Comment: You are missing the last parameter :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `#` as regex delimiter.

```
$result = preg_replace('#http://somesite/(.+)\.png#', '[$1]', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<?php
$text = 'check out this car http://somesite/ford.png'; //get submitted post
$link = strstr($text, 'http://'); //look for an http
$filename = pathinfo ($link, PATHINFO_FILENAME); //get filename from $link
$result = ereg_replace("http://([-]*[.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-?&%])*", "[$filename]", $text); // search on $text, find $link, replace it with $filename

echo $result;

?>
```

Output:

> check out this car [ford]

Or if you wanna link to use forum

```
<?php
$text = 'check out this car http://somesite/ford.png'; //get submitted post
$link = strstr($text, 'http://'); //look for an http
$filename = pathinfo ($link, PATHINFO_FILENAME); //get filename from $link
$result = ereg_replace("http://([-]*[.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-?&%])*", "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $text); // search on $text, find $link, replace it with $filename

echo $result;
?>
```

Or you want to up "ford" as link you can use this:

```
<?php
$text = 'check out this car http://somesite/ford.png'; //get submitted post
$link = strstr($text, 'http://'); //look for an http
$filename = pathinfo ($link, PATHINFO_FILENAME); //get filename from $link
$result = ereg_replace("http://([-]*[.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-?&%])*", "<a href=\"\\0\">$filename</a>", $text); // search on $text, find $link, replace it with $filename

echo $result;

?>
```